# Moq - Mocked Method Response is not returning expected value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Moq Setup:

```
Branch3GInfo mockCasResponse = new Branch3GInfo
{
    Branch3GActiveRouters = new CasApiRouterModelExtendedInfo[]
    {
        new CasApiRouterModelExtendedInfo(12345, "MyRouter", 4, 1, "MyModelType")
    }
};

var mock = new Mock<BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry>(_application);
mock.CallBase = true;

mock.Setup(x => x.GetNodesOn3GBackupAsync()).ReturnsAsync(mockCasResponse);
var mockedObject = mock.Object.GetNodesOn3GBackupAsync().Result;
```

mockedObject contains the mocked response which I have created.

BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry has a method called GetNodesInCriticalCondition().

GetNodesInCriticalCondition() calls GetNodesOn3GBackupAsync() within its body, and then produces some output based on that.  However, it makes this call, **it calls the REAL GetNodesOn3GBackupAsync()**, **and not my mocked version.**  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Please add the code with calling GetNodesInCriticalCondition() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new instance of BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry and then call GetNodesInCriticalCondition and inside of that method you will get mocked result of GetNodesOn3GBackupAsync.

```
var branchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry  = new BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry();
var result = branchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry.GetNodesInCriticalCondition();
```